# Adding another variable information or adding weight into stat_density_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat-density2d

Below is a simple code to produce stat_density_2d plot of X~Y.

```
plot_data <-
  data.frame(X = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)),
             Y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
             Z = c(rnorm(300, 60, 5), rnorm(150, 40, 5)),
             Label = c(rep('A', 300), rep('B', 150)))
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", aes(alpha = stat(level), fill = Label))
```

As I understand, the density is based on the count of X~Y. My question is can I use Z as the density? Or perhaps, add Z as weight to the density? I'm not sure I'm making sense here. As it is the density of X~Y is useful for me. But I'm just wondering if I can add the information in Z into the density of X~Y.

Perhaps you have alternative idea? Both the density of X~Y and Z are information that I want to convey. Currently I'm separating them into separate density X~Y, X~Z, Y~Z, and they're all useful to me (using my data of course).

Edit2, Manual Calculation Plan:
I'm still working on this as I go. This is a general idea of what I'm planning to do.

1. Instead of using stat_density_2d, I plan to calculate the density itself using the method used in stat_density_2d, which is MASS::kde2d().
2. I would then use interpolation such as akima::interp, to interpolate the Z into X~Y grid.
3. I would then multiply Z unto the density of X~Y (from 1) as a form of weightage.
4. Plot them again using ggplot.

Edit 3: Update with code of applying Z as weightage towards density of X~Y.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggnewscale)
library(akima)
library(MASS)

plot_data <-
  data.frame(X = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)),
             Y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
             Z = c(rnorm(300, 60, 5), rnorm(150, 60, 5)),
             Label = c(rep('A', 300), rep('B', 150)))
setDT(plot_data)

#Interpolation of Z into X~Y grid for Label A
int_plot_data_A=with(plot_data[Label=="A"],interp(x=X,y=Y,z=Z,nx=100,ny=100))
rownames(int_plot_data_A$z)=int_plot_data_A$x
colnames(int_plot_data_A$z)=int_plot_data_A$y
plot_data_Z_A <- melt(int_plot_data_A$z)
names(plot_data_Z_A) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

#Calculation of kde2d for Label A
plot_data_A=plot_data[Label=="A"]
kde2d_A=kde2d(plot_data_A$X,plot_data_A$Y,n=100)
rownames(kde2d_A$z)=kde2d_A$x
colnames(kde2d_A$z)=kde2d_A$y
plot_kde_A <- melt(kde2d_A$z, na.rm = TRUE)
names(plot_kde_A) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

#Interpolation of Z into X~Y grid for Label B
int_plot_data_B=with(plot_data[Label=="B"],interp(x=X,y=Y,z=Z,nx=100,ny=100))
rownames(int_plot_data_B$z)=int_plot_data_B$x
colnames(int_plot_data_B$z)=int_plot_data_B$y
plot_data_Z_B <- melt(int_plot_data_B$z)
names(plot_data_Z_B) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

#Calculation of kde2d for Label B
plot_data_B=plot_data[Label=="B"]
kde2d_B=kde2d(plot_data_B$X,plot_data_B$Y,n=100)
rownames(kde2d_B$z)=kde2d_B$x
colnames(kde2d_B$z)=kde2d_B$y
plot_kde_B <- melt(kde2d_B$z, na.rm = TRUE)
names(plot_kde_B) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

#Filtering out values under 0.01. It makes the plot better. This is subjective
setDT(plot_kde_A)
plot_kde_A[Z<0.01]=NA
setDT(plot_kde_B)
plot_kde_B[Z<0.01]=NA

#Calculate for A weighted with Z
plot_kde_A_Weight_Z=plot_kde_A
plot_kde_A_Weight_Z$Z=plot_kde_A_Weight_Z$Z*plot_data_Z_A$Z

#Calculate for B weighted with Z
plot_kde_B_Weight_Z=plot_kde_B
plot_kde_B_Weight_Z$Z=plot_kde_B_Weight_Z$Z*plot_data_Z_B$Z


ggplot() +
  geom_contour_fill(data=plot_kde_A,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=Z),alpha=0.8,bins=10) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "blue") +
  geom_contour(data=plot_kde_A_Weight_Z,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=Z),bins=10) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_contour_fill(data=plot_kde_B,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=Z),alpha=0.8,bins=10) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_contour(data=plot_kde_B_Weight_Z,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=Z),color="red",bins=10)
```

Edit 1: After searching around while dropping keyword ggplot, I found something called kernel density estimation And this post, [Plot contours of distribution on all three axes in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700196/plot-contours-of-distribution-on-all-three-axes-in-3d-plot), feels like this is what I'm looking for to visualise my data. Unfortunately, I found out that ggplot does not have 3D functionality. There's a 4 years package called gg3D? plotly seems to be the best candidate for this? The final figure in the post looks like what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282989/show-only-high-density-areas-with-ggplot2s-stat-density-2d

Comment: @Quinten, I actually took the sample data from that question. However, that question was about controlling the density appearances of X~Y with regards to X~Y. I want to add Z into the density appearance of X~Y.